# Confusion about Differential Equation of Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a simple ODE to solve of matrix.

$\frac{dM}{dt} = \alpha J$

where $M$ and $J$ are matrices. How can I proceed to solve them?

Comment: So $J$ depends only on time?

Comment: For the isolated equation above, J only depends on time.

Answer (score 0):

Just integrate, i.e.
\begin{align}
M(t)_{i,j} = (M_0)_{ij}+\alpha\int^t_{t_0}J(s)_{ij}\ ds.
\end{align}

Comment: ... This "entrywise" (exact) answer means that the matrix structure of your problem is unimportant....

Comment: hey, my main confusion was if the element wise solution can be used. It means each element grow independently and thus, I was concerned if it is fine. Is there any literature I can study on this?